# How to let the user enter the value into the query 'Visual Studio 2012' & 'SQL server'

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2012

I 'm new At visual studio and i want to let the user enter a value into the query

i.e search for an employee I'll use

```
Select * From Employee Where ID = (i want the user to enter the value here)
```

I already connected the database
and I know I can get the value from a text box but i really don't know how to put that value in the query directly and call it immediately

Comment: What have you tried ? Can you post your code? Try this btw. "Select * From Employee Where ID = "+TextBox1.Text;

Comment: @sh4nx0r Bad suggestion, that allows for SQL Injection.  Use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 1):

Parameterizing is relatively simple.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ExecuteSQL("Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=Database;Persist Security Info=True;Integrated Security=True", _
               "Select * From Employee Where ID=@id",
               New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@id", 123))
End Sub

Public Function ExecuteSQL(ByVal Connection As String, _
                      ByVal SQL As String, _
                      ByRef Param As SqlClient.SqlParameter) As System.Data.DataTable
    Try
        Dim dt As System.Data.DataTable = Nothing
        Dim SqlRdr As SqlClient.SqlDataReader

        Using SqlConn As SqlClient.SqlConnection = New SqlClient.SqlConnection(Connection)
            Using SqlCmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(SQL, SqlConn)
                SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                SqlCmd.Parameters.Add(Param)
                SqlConn.Open()
                SqlRdr = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
                Try
                    If SqlRdr.IsClosed = False AndAlso SqlRdr.HasRows = True Then
                        dt = New System.Data.DataTable
                        dt.BeginLoadData()
                        dt.Load(SqlRdr)
                        dt.EndLoadData()
                    End If
                Finally
                    If SqlRdr IsNot Nothing Then
                        SqlRdr.Close()
                    End If
                End Try
            End Using
        End Using

        Return dt
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```